# Programatically clicking on an anchor in Windows UWP WebView

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, uwp

The code contains lots of items with the same href since its an external source I can't help it. I would like to know how do I programatically click on the particular link tag using c# hosted inside a Webview (or even given the source).

```
<div class="vote">
     <ul class="btn-vote left">
           <li><a class="badge-item-vote-up up " href="javascript:void(0);" rel="nofollow">Upvote</a></li>
           <li><a class="badge-item-vote-down down " href="javascript:void(0);" rel="nofollow">Downvote</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does not use your html, but does show how to programmatically clicking on the particular link tag.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="link1" href="http://www.bing.com" >www.bing.com</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In C#, click a xaml button to trigger the click.

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new String[] { "window.location = document.getElementById('link1').href" });
    }
```

Comment: I have a few questions here, 1) What exactly does the eval do? 2) where is the html stored as string in the document?

Comment: Okay I think I got it. The document corresponds to the content in the webview and "eval" is for evaluating the link?

Comment: eval is a special function in js. it evaluates the javascript statement and execute the javascript statement. Actually, if you have a predefined javascript function, you can replace the "eval" to your function name and the other parameter of invokscriptasync is the parameter of your predefined function.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Bear in mind that the above code doesn't actually click on the link but rather gets the target URL and navigates to it. If the link has some onClick events, they won't be invoked. But I guess the OP is fine with that.